# smoke opacity background animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I don't know if this is possible. But I think it is as I feel like I've been close to accidentally doing this by toggling the z-index in the past- but I'm trying to figure out if I can create a 'smokey' background animated, like smoke that's subtly clearing, almost foggy. I feel like the approach would involve my repeating an animated gif of the type of smoke I want, toggling the opacity and stacking order of the z-index so it's somewhat over the content. Does this sound like a legit way to do this? - or is there a better solution? (IE8+)

Comment: Hard to imagine you'd be able to get that to render smoothly with so many layers of opacity.

Comment: There is not a better solution that I can think of if you are targeting IE8. If you are able/allowed to do some graceful degredation, IE9 and better browsers can use this effect: http://designfestival.com/the-cicada-principle-and-why-it-matters-to-web-designers/ which I bet will get you really close to what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example might get you started:
http://media.24ways.org/2009/15/space.html

looks like they use a few different "spinning" divs to create a smoke look.

Full article: http://24ways.org/2009/css-animations

thanks - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194796/jquery-css3-animated-fog

Comment: Thats neat, but not even rendering on FF 8. Looks great in Chrome, though